# Dynamically create predicate with varying criteria and multiple tables for EF 5 and VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, dynamic, predicate

I've been struggling with this one for a while now and I'm hoping someone here can help me out. I have a project written in VB.NET (.NET 4.0, VS 2012) which is using EF 5 and a generic repo/UoW setup. I'm needing to dynamically create predicates to pass to my repo's Where() function, which is implemented as simply:

```
    Public Function Where(predicate As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As IEnumerable(Of T) Implements IDatabaseRepository(Of T).Where
        Return _context.GetDBSet(Of T).Where(predicate).ToList()
    End Function
```

The predicates can get somewhat complex depending on the criteria the user has entered. This is one example of a predicate I am trying to build dynamically.

```
Function(p) p.ProductCategoryID = 56 AndAlso p.ProductLabels.Any(Function(pl) pl.ProductID = p.ProductID AndAlso (pl.LabelID = 2 OrElse pl.LabelID = 3)) AndAlso p.ProductLabels.Any(Function(pl) pl.ProductID = p.ProductID AndAlso pl.LabelID = 27) AndAlso p.ProductPrices.Any(Function(pp) pp.ProductID = p.ProductID AndAlso pp.PriceTypeID = 2 AndAlso pp.Price > 10)
```

If I pass this just like this to the Where function I get the results I expect. I can't figure out how to dynamically create this, though. I've played with the PredicateBuilder, but I couldn't get that working.

The predicate could be as simple as:

```
Function(p) p.SKU.StartsWith("ABC")
```

Or as complex as the one above.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following to do this, but it can get ugly quick. [How to: Use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882637.aspx)